# How to get the 0's of digits when iterating through int's in C

Tags: c

I am trying to iterate through some number as 02100021, this is a routing number which needs to get validated if it is a proper routing number. Therefore I am using the ABA routing number validation check as 3*(d1+d4+d7) + 7*(d2+d5+d8) + (d3+d6+d9) where mod 10 = 0

Since I have the number in integer type, my first question is how can I iterate through such number with 0's in it, or if there is some easier way of iterating through mode and multiplying it with such number.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `7 * (d2, d5, d8)` should be `7 * (d2 + d5 + d8)`.
Zeros modulo 10 do not count.

```
bool correct(long x) { 
    long a = x / 10 + x / 10000 + x / 10000000L;
    long b = x / 100 + x / 100000L + x / 100000000L;
    long c = x / 1000 + x / 1000000L + x / 1000000000L;
    int aba_checksum = (int)((3 * a + 7 * b + c) % 10);
    return aba_checksum == 0;
}
```

---

Corrected for d[i] = digit * 10 ^ (9 - i)

```
bool correct(long x) { 
    long a = x / 100000000L + x / 100000L + x / 100;
    long b = x / 10000000L + x / 10000L + x / 10;
    long c = x / 1000000L + x / 1000L + x;
    int aba_checksum = (int)((3 * a + 7 * b + c) % 10);
    return aba_checksum == 0;
}
```

Modulo arithmetic can be done at the end.
To prevent overflow (to negative numbers) one might do it earlier, above even 7 * b does not overflow.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, as you don't mask off x's previous divisions (i.e. values greater than 10 after the division).  `(x/decimal_place) % 10` would fix that I believe. -- Untested.

Comment: `x / 1000 + x / 1000000L + x / 1000000000L` does not give you the sum of digits 3, 6 and 9. For x=123456789 it gives 123456+123+0=123579, not 3+6+9=18.

Comment: That's correct, I just tried that and the checksum is not coming properly.

Comment: Modulo 10 addition can be done at the end. My problem was, is d[i] = digit*10^(i - 1) or is d indexed from the other side (left to right).

Comment: Then one needs the number of digits (9 it seems). d1 = x / 1_000_000_000L.

Comment: Sorry, a 0 too much for every power of 10. Misses `+ x`!